# What causes: loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00 | TensorFlow 2.0 | Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am working with an LSTM model to predict a personality type according to Myers-Briggs test.

- I created a dataset of (295, 2 (not counting the header)) with personality type labels and their respective description.

**csv file:** [Dataset MBTI |Github](https://github.com/GUNTERMAXIMUS/mbti/blob/master/mbti_new.csv)

- The datasets were divided into their respective matrices:

  > **80%** `(train_data, train_labels)` | **20%** `(validation_data, validation_labels)`.
- Also, the datasets were preprocessed: *tokenized, stopwords, and padded*.

However, at the time of training, the following is shown:

```
Train on 236 samples, validate on 59 samples
Epoch 1/100
236/236 - 1s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/100
236/236 - 1s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/100
236/236 - 1s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/100
236/236 - 1s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/100
236/236 - 1s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/100
236/236 - 2s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/100
236/236 - 1s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/100
236/236 - 2s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/100
236/236 - 2s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/100
236/236 - 1s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

**The LSTM model** is as follows:

```py
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(600, 295))
model.add(keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(590))) model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = 'sigmoid')) # Not sure if using sigmoid | softmax

model.summary()
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, None, 295)         147500    
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, 64)                83968     
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 16)                1040      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 16)                272       
=================================================================
Total params: 232,780
Trainable params: 232,780
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

- I hope that at the time of training, throw a cup of '95%' accuracy, and the normal that corresponds to the rest of the parameters (loss, val_loss, val_acc).
- If the model is not the right one, or if the values ​​are not what you should enter, let me know, like any other suggestion for a better understanding of the question and facilitate the answers.

Comment: softmax is definitely better

Comment: @NicolasGervais yeah I think the same, but I still got the issue.